# What is better for performance - Make a bulk call to DB or single call with a loop for calculation?

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate

I am making an online test with predefined questions and it's correct answer I let student enter their answer to each question and I took them and check them against correct form DB. is it better to call DB to for each answer to check or get all question right answer and make loop o(n)^2.I am using hibernate

Comment: The latter one usually is the more rational choice, no matter scalability-wise or architecture-wise.  However I should still say this is mostly opinion-based, especially when you are asking performance.  It highly depends on how you query the DB, the capacity of your server and DB, and etc

Comment: Clueless on why you said loop `O(N^2)`.  For example, I would have design the model as a `Test` having multiple `Question`, and each `Question` having the correct answer. So you just need to have one roundtrip to DB to get all question + answer for that `Test`.  Then you just have one loop to loop through the student's answer, and verify against corresponding correct `Answer` in `Test`.  By proper design I don't think you need a nested loop.

Comment: on the server side, i have all answers for questions given by the student  . I need to give him grade regarding his choice . as you said i will call DB once with questions and correct answers. then i have to make this on nested  loop or what do you think

Comment: You don't need nested loop with proper design.  E.g. you can have your Test capable to return you answer of a question by index.  So you just need one loop, and the lookup from `Test` could be `O(1)`.  Most important is, with proper model design, your code looks much nicer

Comment: dear Adrian .last thing. my user will submit all answers to all 1000 question on time. and I have to correct them, i have a multi-choice question with one to many relation to answer. how can i check given answers on o(1) or o(n). can I ?

Comment: Still it depends on your design.  For example, in `Question` I can expose a method `boolean isCorrect(Set<Character> providedAnswers)` which do a simple `return providedAnswers.equals(correctAnswers);` if I have a `Set<Character> correctAnswers` in my `Question` (You may even use a `BitSet` instead).  Whether internally the `Set` comparison is O(n) or O(1), it is less of your interest unless it is really a performance bottleneck (which I don't think it will be), but your code looks clean without complicated nested loops

Comment: especially you are using Hibernate, I expect you want to have proper domain model which provides proper behavior, instead of still a two-tier application that you stuff logic in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bulk operation is the best. It requires a single database roundtrip and you can do all the processing in the database so that you don't have to move one million records back and forth the DB.

For more details about Bulk Updates, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-api-bulk-update-delete/).

In your example, it does not matter if the user had a test with 1000 questions. If they have a predefined right answer, you can match that in the DB automatically.

If you need to manually validate answers, do it with [batch processing](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and process only N answers at a time and send all answers in a single batch to the DB.